# In scalar subquery getting error in column alias

Tags: sql, mysql, subquery, scalar-subquery

```
Select Movie_Title , cast(replace(Box_Office_Revenue_,'$','') as signed) movieCol
From sales.google_movie_data movie
Join (Select round(avg(replace(Box_Office_Revenue_,"$","")),2) as col
from sales.google_movie_data) avg_col
On movie.movieCol > avg_col.col;
```

Error: Unknown column 'movie.movieCol' in 'on clause'

Why am I getting error here and how to resolve it?

Using MySQL

Comment: Think it will be on `cast(replace(Box_Office_Revenue_,'$','') as signed)`

Comment: Didn't get you, sorry

Comment: you can't use select field aliases in where or on clauses; you have to repeat the expression instead, so `On cast(replace(Box_Office_Revenue_,'$','') as signed) > avg_col.col`